# SmsManager doesn't work

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

i have issue with SmsManager...i show you my snippet:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String phoneNumberReciver="";
        String message="";
        SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumberReciver, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered and SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }


}
```

IDE say me that SmsManager is deprecated...so what can i use instead SmsManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager` is deprecated. Just use `android.telephony.SmsManager` instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

set permission in minfest file

Answer (score 0):

Use **import android.telephony.SmsManager**

Rest of your code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

use below import for SmsManager and permission
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"